# pandas read_csv cannot use dtype does not work on the column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data

```
PERMNO Names,Date,Ticker Symbol,Company Name,CUSIP Header
10000,19851231,,,68391610
10000,19860331,OMFGA,OPTIMUM MANUFACTURING INC,68391610
10001,19851231,,,36720410
10001,19860131,GFGC,GREAT FALLS GAS CO,36720410
10001,19860228,GFGC,GREAT FALLS GAS CO,36720410
```

I have the following data

```
PERMNO Names,Date,Ticker Symbol,Company Name,CUSIP Header
10000,19851231,,,68391610
10000,19860331,OMFGA,OPTIMUM MANUFACTURING INC,68391610
10001,19851231,,,36720410
10001,19860131,GFGC,GREAT FALLS GAS CO,36720410
10001,19860228,GFGC,GREAT FALLS GAS CO,36720410
```

I am coming this command

```
pd.read_csv(csv_file_path, index_col=["CUSIP Header"],
            dtype = {"CUSIP Header": str}, usecols =["Date", "CUSIP Header"], 
            parse_dates=['Date'])
```

however, it seems like the CUSIP Headers are not parsed as str but as floats. Indeed when I tried to call

```
print (actual.xs("68391610"))
```

I got a key error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [bug 9435](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9435), so remove `index_col` parameter and use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path,
            dtype = {'CUSIP Header': str}, usecols =["Date", "CUSIP Header"], 
            parse_dates=['Date']).set_index('CUSIP Header')

print (df)
                   Date
CUSIP Header           
68391610     1985-12-31
68391610     1986-03-31
36720410     1985-12-31
36720410     1986-01-31
36720410     1986-02-28

print (df.index)
Index(['68391610', '68391610', '36720410', '36720410', '36720410'],
       dtype='object', name='CUSIP Header')
```

Comment: LOL, okay, for once, it is not a user error from me. thank you for the confirmation and solution.

Comment: Glad can help, nice day!